# React-hook-form's handleSubmit is getting called when uploading file but haven't clicked submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have multiple choices of documents for the user to upload, and other text input fields too. When I **upload a file**, the `onSubmit` function in `SignUp.tsx` is getting called (i can see the log statement is executed in the `onSubmit` func) , even when I didn't hit the `submit` button of the form. I have verified that the files are infact uploading, as they are in the payload as seen from the console statement in the `onSubmit` function.

SignUp.tsx:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import FormProvider from './hook-form/FormProvider';
import RHFInput from './hook-form/RHFInput';
import DocUpload from './DocUpload';

const Documents = [
    {
        name: 'doc-certificate',
        label: 'Certificate',
    },
    {
        name: 'doc-license',
        label: 'License',
    },
    {
        name: 'doc-examResult',
        label: 'Exam Result',
    },
]

type SelectedFiles = {
    [key: string]: File | null;
};

export default function DriverSignUp() {
    const methods = useForm();
    const { handleSubmit } = methods;

    const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState<SelectedFiles>({});

    const handleFileChange = (name: string, file: File | null) => {
        const newSelectedFiles: SelectedFiles = { ...selectedFiles };

        if (file) {
            newSelectedFiles[name] = file;
        } else {
            delete newSelectedFiles[name];
        }
        setSelectedFiles(newSelectedFiles);
    };


    const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
        const formDataWithFiles = { ...data, ...selectedFiles };
        console.log(formDataWithFiles); // this gets executed when i try to submit files, but haven't hit the submit button yet
    };

    return (
        <FormProvider methods={ methods } onSubmit={ handleSubmit(onSubmit) } className = "grid grid-cols-10 gap-4" >
            {/* Left col */ }
            <div className="col-span-6 p-4" >
                // text inputs for name, email, etc, like
                <RHFInput name="homeAddress" type="text" />

            </div>

            {/* Right col */ }
            <div className="col-span-4 p-4">
                <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Documents</h2>

                <div className="mb-4 flex flex-col gap-2">
                    {Documents.map((doc) => (
                        <DocUpload key={doc.name} name={doc.name} label={doc.label} onFileChange={handleFileChange} />
                    ))}
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </FormProvider>
    );
};
```

DocUpload.tsx:

```
import { useRef, useState, ChangeEvent } from "react";

interface DocUploadProps {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    onFileChange: (name: string, file: File | null) => void;
}

export default function DocUpload({ name, label, onFileChange }: DocUploadProps) {
    const hiddenInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);

    const handleFileChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        // const newFile = event.target.files && event.target.files[0];
        const newFile = event.currentTarget.files && event.currentTarget.files[0];

        if (newFile) {
            onFileChange(name, newFile);
            setFile(newFile);
        }
    };

    const onUpload = () => {
        hiddenInputRef.current?.click();
    };

    const onView = () => {
        if (file) {
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileURL, "_blank");
        }
    };

    const onRemoveFile = () => {
        onFileChange(name, null);
        setFile(null);
    };

    const uploadButtonLabel = file ? `Change ${label}` : label;

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="file"
                name={name}
                className="hidden"
                ref={hiddenInputRef}
                onChange={handleFileChange}
            />

            <button className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded" onClick={onUpload}>
                {uploadButtonLabel}
            </button>

            {file && (
                <>
                    <span className="ml-2 cursor-pointer text-blue-500 underline" onClick={onView}>
                        View
                    </span>
                    <span className="ml-2 cursor-pointer text-red-500 underline" onClick={onRemoveFile}>
                        Remove
                    </span>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

FormProvider.tsx:

```
import { FormProvider as Form } from 'react-hook-form';

interface FormProviderProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    methods: any;
    onSubmit?: any;
    className?: string;
}

export default function FormProvider({ children, onSubmit, methods, className }: FormProviderProps) {
    return (
        <Form {...methods}>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className={className}>{children}</form>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

example of how i use the text field RHFInput.tsx:

```
import { useFormContext, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';

export interface RHFInputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
    name: string;
}

export default function RHFInput({ name, ...other }: RHFInputProps) {
    const { control } = useFormContext();

    return (
        <Controller
            name={name}
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
                <input
                    {...field}
                    {...other}
                    value={field.value || ''}
                    className={`p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded w-full text-black leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 ${other.className}`}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Passing an arrow function like

```js
()=>{handleSubmit(onsubmit)}
```

in `onclick` as it will not then call directly whenever the data gets in `onsubmit` value.

Comment: That didn't work either, I managed to make a custom RHFDocUpload similar to how I wrapped the `input` in `RHFInput`. Now it works. I think it was some issue with the form having multiple contexts for forms (as the file inputs were separate, and not being managed by react-hook-forms)